# Creating a Service of redis to Cloud Foundry applications using Cloud Foundry CLI

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Using the Cloud Foundry CLI in IBM Bluemix
To Cloud Foundry applications
I want to create and bind the Service.

**Environment**
OS:Windows10
cf version:6.21.1+cd086c8-2016-08-18
npm version:3.10.3

**Procedure**
Cloud Foundry applications already created from UI

1. Log in to the IBM Bluemix from the Windows command prompt
2. Example: Creating a "redis" service in cf create-service command

   ```
   cf create-service redis 100 test-redis
   ```
3. An error

   ```
   FAILED
   Service offering redis not found
   ```

Becomes the above-mentioned, an error message is no service of redis is output,
It will not be able to create a service.

The first place it is not possible to create a service of redis from CLI,
Or such as the service command specified redis is wrong.

Comment: What Bluemix region are you logged in? Could you please check this with the `cf target` command?

Comment: I used the command. 
API endpoint: api.au-syd.bluemix.net (API version: 2.54.0) 
Bluemix Region I is logged is Sydney.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redis service is not available in the Bluemix Sydney region. 
You can check for all services available in the Sydney region using the following command:

`$ cf marketplace`

You can use the redis service in the US South or United Kingdom regions.
To use the US South region run, set the API endpoint to:

`$ cf api api.ng.bluemix.net`

For United Kingdom:

`$ cf api api.eu-gb.bluemix.net`

You will have to `cf login` again after setting the new API endpoint.
You may also have to create an organization and/or space if this is first time you login to these regions.

Comment: Well, it was not available in the Sydney Region! Thank you!